# How to hide default hamburger icon of Navigation view android

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I need to hide the hamburger icon

[image]

[image]

This is my toolbar

I need to hide the default hamburger icon of navigation bar and load it from another button click.The navigation bar need to appear on the attachment icon  click in my toobar and need to disappear when i click outside(anywhere).Can this be done ?

Comment: can i you post your code so that improvement can be done

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` to remove home button and inflate the menu on `onCreateOptionsMenu` then open and close drawer using `onOptionsItemSelected` on button that you want to open drawer

Answer (score 17):

if you are using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` then you can add a line:

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

and `opening` and `closing` drawer you can write in your click event:

```
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else {
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can hide the hamburger icon by doing this:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);          // to hide Navigation icon
toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // to hide back button
```

If you have added the attachment icon **manually** (As an `imageView` inside a `Toolbar`) :

```
boolean isDrawerOpen = false;
imageViewAttachment..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              if(!isDrawerOpen) {
                  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                  isDrawerOpen = true;
              }
              else {
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                  isDrawerOpen = false;
              }
            }
        });
```

Or, if you've added as a `Menu` item :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.attachment:
                if(!isDrawerOpen) {
                  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                  isDrawerOpen = true;
                }
                else {
                  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                  isDrawerOpen = false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```