# How to hide icon of NavigationView if click icon search android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer.I have problem with icon of NavigationView.If I click on search icon it's come at the bottom. This question may have been asked a lot time before now, but I could not find an answer to my question.

Like this:
[image]

[image]

As you can see in two photo I have problem if I click or not click.

XML coed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />

    

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

menu of icon search:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />


</menu>
```

Code of search:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Add your menu entries here
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (mExampleAdapter==null){

                }else {
                    mExampleAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });



        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

```
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I don't know how I can solve this problem>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide default hamburger icon of Navigation view android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572122/how-to-hide-default-hamburger-icon-of-navigation-view-android)

Comment: @NajiMakhoul in that example looks like its about the drawer icon not the overflow menu icon which is the current case here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //...

    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should override this method

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return false;
}
```

but its impossible to do so at runtime using plain java
I think should instead render all options in the overflow menu icon invisible on click if they are many